# Positive-definite matrix with simple structure

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

The $n\times n$ matrix $A$ has this specific structure:

- The diagonal entries $a_{ii}$ are strictly increasing and strictly positive real numbers;
- The non-diagonal entries are calculated as $a_{ij}=a_{ji}=a_{ii}$ where $i$ is the smaller index. In other words, $a_{ij}=a_{ji}=\min(a_{ii},a_{jj})$.

Is the matrix $A$ positive-definite?

For the $1\times1$ case, the result is trivial. For the $2\times2$ case, we can use [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) and see that $a_{11}a_{22}-a_{11}^2>0$ is true, so $A$ is positive-definite.

Is there an argument that can be used to extend this result to larger matrices?

###### Some empirical results

I generated one million $20\times20$ matrices using an exponential random variable for the diagonal. Every random matrix is positive-definite. I expect this result to be true in general but I just don't find a proof.

Comment: If $a_{ij}=a_{ii}$, then all the columns would be the same, so the determinant of the matrix would be $0$ if $n>1$. The determinant in the $2 \times 2$ case assumes that $a_{12}=a_{21}=a_{11}$, which seems to contradict $a_{ij}=a_{ii}$ for $i=2$ and $j=1$.

Comment: No, the columns are not the same. I tried empirically many matrices and I always get only positive eigenvalues. I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! So, $a_{ij}=a_{ii}$ should hold only if $i<j$ (otherwise, $a_{ij}=a_{jj}$ if $i>j$), and the matrix would then be symmetric as required for positive-definite matrices. In the original revision, the equation could easily be misunderstood to hold for all $i \ne j$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a_{ii}=s_1+\cdots+s_i$ implies that

$$\sum_{i,j}a_{i,j}x_ix_j=s_1(x_1+\cdots+x_n)^2+s_2(x_2+\cdots+x_n)^2+\cdots+s_nx_n^2\geq 0.$$

Comment: Very neat simple proof!